# Maven Unicode Encoding build failure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unicode, utf-8

I have a test that passes in eclipse but fails in Maven due to a unicode problem. The test uses this character: ä - the test checks the length of the character, in eclipse its one but maven converts it to 2 characters: ├ñ. Does anyone know how I can get maven to behave the same as eclipse?

So far I have tried adding

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

to the pom for both the root and the project the test sits in. Plus I have tried adding directly to the maven plugin part of the pom as follows:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>2.1</version>-->
<configuration>
  <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
</configuration>
```

Eclipse is set to use UTF-8. Im running out of ideas. If there is anything im obviously doing wrong please let me know.

Why is this working fine in Eclipse but not Maven?!

Thanks,

Comment: Did you ensure that the file containing `ä` is encoded in UTF-8? For example, by looking at the hex dump of the file.

Comment: How do i ensure that? like where can i find the hex dump? I inspected the file in eclipse and it is set to UTF-8...

Comment: If you are on windows and don't have any text editors that could do it, you could try this http://ehep.sourceforge.net/ You would then inspect to see if the byte sequence `0xC3 0xA4` is in place of `ä`

Comment: Iv installed the plugin, quick question - how do use it? There doesnt seem to be any instructions on how to open it in eclipse.

Comment: why not just remove the unicode character from your source file per my answer?

Comment: Well its a test, the whole point is that we are testing to see what happens when users type these characters in as it will be used in different countries. We cant make the user type in unicode charcters whenever they wish to have a non-english letter

Comment: the form of the character in your source code has nothing to do with how users are typing them in.  unless your users are typing in actual java source code.

Comment: Iv inspected the object in the hex editor and it is indeed 0xC3 0xA4

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to avoid using unicode characters in your source files.  instead, use the unicode escape syntax, i.e. `"\u00E4"`.

Comment: care to explain the downvote?  my answer is a legitimate solution to the problem even if the OP doesn't realize it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this in the plugin's configuration:

```
<plugin>
    ...
    <configuration>
        ...
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I tried this and it still failed. Tried it with <outputEncoding> as well but that fails as well...